# There is no translational symmetry for bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\Omega \subset R^n$ be a bounded subset, *i.e.* there exists a constant $M$ such that $d(x,y)<M$ for any $x, y \in \Omega$. Show that any translation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot leave $\Omega$ invariant.

Comment: False: Take $D$ to be the discrete metric and $\Omega =\mathbb R^{n}$ to get a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Kavi Rama Murthy this is not true whenever whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded. This happens when the metric itself is bounded, e.g. with the discrete metric or for $\min(1,d(\cdot, \cdot))$ metric (this particular choice shows that any metrizable topology can be induced from a metric not having this property).

This is true, however, when we deal with a metric induced by a norm (not necessarily Euclidean), instead of arbitrary metric.

Indeed, the requirement is equivalent to: for any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ there is $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $v+\omega\not\in\Omega$.

*Proof.* So assume that's not the case. So $v\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ is fixed and $v+\omega\in\Omega$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$. Take any $\omega\in\Omega$ and define $\omega_n=nv+\omega$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By our assumption $\omega_n\in\Omega$ for any $n$.

Note that $v+\frac{1}{n}\omega$ converges to $v\neq 0$ (we use the property of norms that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous) and thus

$$\lVert\omega_n\rVert= \lVert nv+\omega\rVert =|n|\cdot\lVert v+\frac{1}{n}\omega\rVert$$

diverges to $\infty$. We used norm here to take the "$n$" component outside of the norm.

And so $\omega_n$ is an unbounded sequence that belongs to $\Omega$. Contradiction. $\Box$